# How to use SPSS if condition for various variables?

Tags: if-statement, variables, spss

Here the variable V4_15 is corralated to V4_15_0, V4_15_1, V4_15_2, V4_15_3, V4_15_4, V4_15_5, V4_15_6, V4_15_7.

If those later variables are 0 then V4_15 is 0 (Absent) and if any of those variables is 1 then V4_15 is 1 (present).

Any idea how can I do this using Transform > Compute variable?

I am a beginner level user. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a new syntax window and run it:

```
compute V4_15 = any(1, V4_15_0 to V4_15_7).
execute.
```

In general I recommend learning to use syntax - after a bit of getting used to it will get you much further, much quicker.